# Конвертация кода из java в с++

Tags: java, c++

Есть код, написанный на *Java*:

```
    public class KeyCallback extends GLFWKeyCallback
    {
        public static final boolean[] keys = new boolean[65536];

        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
        {
            keys[key] = action != GLFW.GLFW_RELEASE;
        }
    }
```

Как написать то же самое, только на *C++*?

Comment: весь класс переписать на си++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*KeyCallback.h*

```
class KeyCallback : public GLFWKeyCallback {
    public :
        static bool keys[];
        void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) override;
}
```

*KeyCallback.cpp*

```
void KeyCallback::invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    keys[key] = action != GLFW.GLFW_RELEASE;
}

bool KeyCallback::keys[] = new bool[65536]
```

Comment: Спасибо! я просто объявление массива делал keys[65536] и из за этого получал ошибки)